# Failed to process JAR found at URL [] for ServletContainerInitializers

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, servlet-container

I'm upgrading a service from Tomcat 7 -> Tomcat 8, and I'm encountering this issue just now that I'm kinda at a loss for.

Here is the stack trace:

```
    SEVERE: Failed to process JAR found at URL [] for ServletContainerInitializers for context with name [{1}]
java.net.MalformedURLException: no !/ in spec
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:619)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:482)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:431)
    at java.net.JarURLConnection.parseSpecs(JarURLConnection.java:179)
    at java.net.JarURLConnection.<init>(JarURLConnection.java:162)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.<init>(JarURLConnection.java:81)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:41)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:971)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.parseConfigFile(WebappServiceLoader.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: no !/ in spec
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.Handler.parseAbsoluteSpec(Handler.java:170)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.Handler.parseURL(Handler.java:150)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:614)
    ... 24 more
```

I know that the whole "URL []" and "context with name [{1}]" looks bad, but I don't know why, or how these values were set the way they were. Can anyone please point me in the right direction as to what's going on?

Comment: Anyone? The Tomcat doc isn't super helpful with this.

Comment: You may delete the temp folder or other tomcat built-in folders

Comment: Did this ever get solved? I am having a similar issue.